# PHP Variables echoing properly but not entering into the database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to enter 5 variables into a MySQL database. Here is the code:

```
    foreach ($avail_t as $row) {
    $ava = explode("+",$row);
    $day = $ava[0];
    $from = $ava[1];
    $to = $ava[2];
    //echo $day." ".$from." ".$to;
    $query = "INSERT INTO availability (username, login_value, day, from, to) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['username']}', '{$_SESSION['login_value']}', '{$day}', '{$from}', '{$to}')";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

When I uncomment that echo statement all variables print out just fine, but when I process the query it doesn't enter into the database. Weirdly, if I cut out $from and $to and just enter $day it will enter the day. When I put back the $from and $to nothing gets entered.

Do you see any problems with this code? Data type is integer in military time format 2100, 1300 etc. for $from and $to.

Comment: check mysql_error() for any syntax errors, as well as the return value of mysql_query

Comment: Try to `echo $query;`, to make sure it contains what you think it does.

Comment: For future users seeing your questions. If you know this, great! [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [prepared statements](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Jeremy1026: https://gist.github.com/3881905

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `from` and `to` as a column name which are [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html), escape them using backticks `` ` `` in your query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO availability (username, login_value, day, `from`, `to`) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$_SESSION['login_value']."', '$day', '$from', '$to')";
```

Comment: Need backticks for `to` as well

Comment: It's considered good practice to blindly surround all table/database names with backticks, be it a reserved word or not.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I have never heard that before. I have heard it's **better** practice to not used reserved words.

Comment: Perfect! I actually just changed the names altogether to prevent any issues later down the line. Thank you!

Comment: @Arun that's what you should do, be sure you ignore reserved words henceforth

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `from` or `to`, those are reserved words.

Comment: looks like he can just need to surrounded with `

Comment: This is frowned upon since it can lead to confusions like this